# Setting the active workbook as that which the macro has been run from

Tags: excel, vba

I was very kindly provided with some code by User: Smartini

Works entirely as intended although I'd like to make a small change. The macro copies and pastes data between workbooks, although the workbook from which I'd like to copy changes every time, always with a randomly generated file name.

I'd like to save the below code in the Personal Macro Workbook, and have it run with the initial workbook being defined as that which the macro has been run from.

Hope I've been clear enough and look forward to seeing if anyone can help!

```
Sub CopyToAnotherWorkbook()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim LastRow_wb%: LastRow_wb = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim arr() As Variant
ReDim arr(0 To LastRow_wb - 1)

For i = 1 To LastRow_wb
    arr(i - 1) = ws.Cells(i, 1)
Next i

Dim wb2 As Workbook: Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Book2.xlsx") ' <- 
Paste 
your Link to the Workbook here!

Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(1)
Dim LastRow_wb2%: LastRow_wb2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 
"A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

If LastRow_wb2 = 2 Then
    LastRow_wb2 = 1
End If

ws2.Range("A" & LastRow_wb2 & ":A" & LastRow_wb2 + UBound(arr)).Value =         
WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
wb2.Close True
Set ws2 = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "that which the macro has been run from" mean if it's in your Personal Workbook? How do you intend to kick off this subroutine "From a workbook"? Via a button or something?

Comment: I *think* what you want is `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @JNevill I mean the workbook that i've got open at that instant, and then I'd just use a keyboard shortcut to activate it

Comment: In that case, I think you just want to change `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook` to `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @JNevill Nice one!! Works perfectly :D